# My sister is two years old. Which are the nouns in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

As far as my understanding goes, the nouns in this sentence are-
sister and years. But my daughter's teacher says 'years' is not a noun and 'two' is a noun. But I think 'years' is a noun as it denotes a time period and 'two' in this sentence will be an adjective as it qualifies 'years'.

Comment: Your daughter's teacher is wrong.

Comment: Both *two* and *years* are nouns. However, in this sentence they are being used as if they were adjectives. For example, *my sister is **very** old*, *my sister is **slightly** old*, or *my sister is **two-years** old*. When used adjectivally, they are often referred to as **attributive nouns**. So, depending on context, *two* and *years* might not be considered to be normal nouns in terms of how the syntax is being analyzed. Having said that, I find it impossible to analyze *two* and *years* as being different types of syntactical units here. Whatever one is, the other is the same.

Comment: At least inasmuch as they act as a combined modifier of *old*. So, unless the analysis is focusing on something else, both you *and* your teacher are wrong …